# Laravel Vite ReferenceError

Tags: laravel, vite

I am looking for help with an error relating to Vite. Trying to import ApexCharts into a new Laravel app using Vite.

Following steps on the ApexCharts installation docs: https://apexcharts.com/docs/installation/

NPM installation was successful. I've added the import to my app.js file:

```
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
```

Running Vite servier with npm run dev. I do not get any errors.

I am trying to load a stripped down blade file for troubleshooting:

```
@vite(['resources/js/app.js']);

<div id="test"></div>

<script type="module">
    var options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'sales',
            data: [30,40,35,50,49,60,70,91,125]
        }],
        xaxis: {
            categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]
        }
    }

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById('test'), options);

    chart.render();
</script>
```

I get the error:

```
(index):19 Uncaught ReferenceError: ApexCharts is not defined
    at (index):19:17
```

I tried running npm run build and the ApexCharts import is in the build asset.

I was thinking it might be a loading order issue, but I get the uncaught reference error even if I try to create a new ApexCharts after the page has finished loading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
window.ApexCharts = ApexCharts; // return apex chart
```

based on the `apexcharts.js` in order to import it you need to define the variables for it first
and you need to expose it via `window.ApexCharts` in order to use it outside webpack bundle